# Are there any libraries available in nodejs for logging into csv?

Tags: node.js, csv, logging, analytics

Although I have found so many libraries which are actually logging in json format but my requirement is bit different and I want to record all logs into csv file with async feature.

Answer (score 0):

You can have alook into [node-csv-parser](https://github.com/wdavidw/node-csv-parser#readme) : 
This project provides CSV generation, parsing, transformation and serialization for Node.js.

You can also have a look at other CSV parsers also come up when you npm search csv